# Where to put constants, parameters, etc. in Python code for research?

Tags: python, code-organization

Context: I'm currently implementing a predictive model of some environmental process. Imagine a model that computes some ecosystem's reaction to different temperatures if you want.

This is the first time I do something like this in Python, and I am kinda usure about how to organize my files. I have read related questions, but they mostly seem to be about different use-cases and/or deal with more in-depth questions, not about where to put constants, parameters, etc.

To give you an example of what I have now:

constants.py:

```
# these should never be touched
CONST1 = 1
CONST2 = 2
# etc
```

parameters.py:

```
# these can and should be changed by the user
par1 = 1
par2 = 2
par3 = 3
# etc
```

model.py:

```
# here are the model's functions
import constants as c

def fun1(par1, par2):
    res1 = c.CONST1 * par1 + par2
    return res1

def fun2(par2, par3):
    res2 = c.CONST2 * par2 + par3
    return res2
# etc
```

main.py:

```
# this file is used to run the model
import model as m
import parameters as p

res1 = m.fun1(p.par1, p.par2)
res2 = m.fun2(p.par2, p.par3)
# plot results etc
```

Is it a good idea to keep constants, parameters and functions in separate files like this, or should at least the constants be global variables in model.py since I don't touch them anyway? Is the "extreme case" of a one-file-solution (constants, parameters, models and a main-function in one .py) considered bad style? What about variables that pretty much any function uses (e.g. time, or the constants that I import in model.py): Should I explicitly pass them to every function, or can/should I make them global?

TL;DR: If there is any best practice for how to organize projects like this, please help a newbie programmer out.

Comment: This is no right or wrong answer to this question and peoples needs vary as the project grows, but in my opinion, separation makes it much easier to find what to change. I normally have a constants.py per package (every folder containing an __init__.py).

Comment: You could have a look at how other scientific packages do it - for example, `numpy` is open source, so you can see their code: https://github.com/numpy/numpy

Comment: As this really depends on the project and how the code is going to be used, there's no one-size-fits-all answer.

Answer (score 1):

This question is primarily opinion-based, but I'll give this a try.

If you don't want to give the user access to constants, only to parameters, you are pretty much doing it right (one file for constants and a separate one for params).

If you don't mind the user being able to change constants, I would advise to have a single file named settings.py, from where you import your constants and whatnot. Remember that Python allows selective importing, which means that if you only need 1 constant inside one of your `.py` files, you can import that single constant, so it's not a matter of efficiency. I would not keep all constants in a single file, unless the project is small.

Apart from that, I would also advise that you store model-specific variables / constants as static properties inside the model class. For example, we could have a school grade model defined like this:

```
class GradeModel(BaseModel):
    GRADE_TYPES = (
        (1, 'Exam'),
        (2, 'Final Paper'),
    ) # this is just an example

    id = IntFieldType()
    student_id = IntFieldType()
    type = ChoiceType(choices=GRADE_TYPES)
    value = IntFieldType()
```

This way, you could call the grade type constant as `GradeModel.GRADE_TYPES`. Note that the above code is more like pseudo-code, because models are primarily dependent on which framework / library you're using, but you get the gist of it.

Comment: The notion of a "model" layer doesn't imply any framework / library / "BaseModel" class or whatsoever, it's just a (sane) way to decouple your code's core features (the domain) from orthogonal concerns like presentation, UI, persistance etc.

Comment: I meant that *if* you use a library / framework, the definition of the models relies on what you're using.